# How do you update a Parent data with only function calls from the child with no event - Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, parent-child

I have a parent and a child component. I want to pass data from child to parent.
If a function is called within the child component, is there a way to update and pass data in the child component to the parent component?

Looking online, most examples involve clicking a button in the child component then sending to the parent. But in my case, there is no clicking a button event, only if a function is called.

How would we do this? Thank you

Comment: in your function call: `this.$emit("eventName", data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you were trying to avoid events only because you assumed the event had to come from a button click, but that's not true. The event could be a function called after a timeout, for example. For direct child to parent data communication, events *are* commonly used to pass data up from the child.

[`vm.$emit()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit) can be used in the child to pass data to the parent:

```js
// Child.vue
export default {
  mounted() {
    // aritifical delay
    setTimeout(() => this.emitDataToParent({ foo: true }), 1000)
  },
  methods: {
    emitDataToParent(data) {
      this.$emit('my-event', data)
    }
  }
}
```

The parent component can add an event handler with [`v-on:EVENT_NAME`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on) (or use `@EVENT_NAME` for shorthand) to receive the child's data:

```html
<template>
  <Child @my-event="handleMyEvent" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    handleMyEvent(data) {
      console.log(data)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/passing-data-from-child-to-parent-in-vue-9htro?file=/src/components/Parent.vue)

Comment: Awesome thanks for all your help and the demo code! Yes that was my assumption, I assumed it all had to be actions from the user to be considered an event. But I'm glad it's not